# How to load hyper link tag in webview

Tags: android

can anybody tell how to load hyper link tag in webview

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You are overriding the loading of all URLs by forcing the WebView to load them with this code

   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       Log.i(TAG, "Loading...");
       view.loadUrl(url);
       return true;
   }
The code would be something like..

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple.

Just create your HTML string and load it inside the webview using `webview.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8");`.

For more information, refer this [Android doc for WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).